# c++ aligning the same word in a text file in different lines/positions to the same position in each line

Tags: c++, file, io, text-alignment

I am wondering how to go through a text file and locate a given word ("foobar") at different locations within each line but then realign the word to the same position in a new text file, let me know if this doesn't make sense.

```
***in text file***
1 foobar baz
2  foobar baz
3   foobar baz

****out text file***
1     foobar baz
2     foobar baz
3     foobar baz
```

Comment: You have to at minimum give us a clue as to how you attempted to solve this.  I suggest you dig into Google first and write some minimal code and then come back and post your attempted solution. Lets see you open the file first and find all the pointer locations to 'foobar'.  Only then will our help be justified.  These are all hints, but not answers.  Think about all the variables you will need to complete your task.  The reason for theses responses is that this question sounds like 'do my homework'.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to ask such a vague question, I had tried googling things but couldn't find anything specific to what I was looking for, and don't really understand enough about C++ to piece together what to do.

Comment: I am trying to align a compiled text or amazon sales for direct inputting into an excel sheet, but I think I am just going to try looking into python or VBA and cutting out the aligning altogether.  Thanks for the responses.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The io manipulator std::setw() from  can be used to create fixed-length columns in text output, and std::setfill() is used to specify the fill character:

```
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << 5 << std::endl;
```

Will print:

```
00005
```

This can easily be used to create a small program which reads all lines from one file and writes them to another file and at the same time aligns all columns (in the below program >> is used to read one column, which means that the columns in the in file are supposed space-separated, by one or more whitespace characters):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

int main (int argc, char* arv[])
{
   using namespace std;

   std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > records;
   std::map<int, int> column_widths;

   std::ifstream in_file("infile.txt", std::ios::text);
   if (!in_file.is_open())
       return 1;

   std::ofstream out_file("outfile.txt", std::ios::text);
   if (!out_file.is_open())
       return 2;

   // read all the lines and columns into records
   std::string line;
   while (std::getline(in_file, line)) {
       std::istringstream is(line);
       std::vector<std::string> columns;
       std::string word;
       int column_index = 0;
       while (is >> word) {
           columns.push_back(word);
           column_widths[column_index] = std::max(column_width[column_index], word.length());
           ++column_index;
       }

       records.push_back(columns);
   }

   // now print all the records and columns with fix widths
   for (int line = 0; line < records.size(); ++line) {
       const std::vector<std::string>& cols = records[line]; 
       for (int column = 0; column < cols.size(); ++column) {
           out_file << std::setw(column_widths[column])
                    << std::setfill(' ')
                    << cols[column] << ' ';
       }
       out_file << "\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I didn't compile the program but it should work :).